# How to check if a variable contains a specific number?

Tags: c

The code is supposed to take any number input from the user and show the next 19 numbers. how ever it's supposed to skip any number that has 3,6,9 in it.

I managed to write a code that can do that, but only until the number 100.
And I managed to write another code that can take any input from the user and tell you whether it has a specific number or not. But I couldn't combine the two codes.

This code works correctly until the number 100:

```
int A, B;
printf("Enter a number");
scanf("%d", &A);
int C;
int D = 20;
int F = 100;
for (; ; A++) {
    B = A % 10;
    C = A / 10;
    if (B == 3 || B == 6 || B == 9 || C == 3 || C == 6 || C == 9) {
        continue;
    }
    else {
        printf("%d\n", A);
            D = D - 1;
    }
    if (D == 1) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This code can work on any number you insert any any number you want to find:

```
int A, B;
printf("Enter a number");
scanf_s("%d", &A);
while (A > 0)
{
    B = A % 10;
    A = A / 10;
    if (B == 3)
    {
        printf("there is a 3 in the givin number");
    }
}
```

The two codes combined should give an output like:
e.g. user input: 127
output:
128
140
141
142
144
145
147
148
150
151
152
154
.
.
.

I tried to combine the codes, but I always got 130, 131... which is undesirable output.

Comment: First format your code correctly, please. Then we'll see what we can do your you. Also show a [MCVE] instead of random snippets of code. You can [edit] your question. Also read this: [ask]

Comment: Why not put your second code snippet into a function, extend it to handle multiple of 3 also and return an appropriate value. Then call it for each of your numbers `A..A+19`

Comment: Convert to string first, then check the string characters for the forbidden digits

Comment: Hint: your first job is to write a function that tells you if a number has a 3, 6, or 9 in it. Then the "outer" function becomes trivial. Don't try and do this all in one function - it will get messy.

Comment: take your working code 2, make it a function `int check3( int A )` that returns 1 if `A` contains a 3 and 0 otherwise and use that function within the loop in code 1

Comment: There is also something wrong with your brackets.

Answer (score 4):

Set up a look-up table with forbidden digits, then check each digit of the number against it, no matter the number's size. Essentially what your code is already doing.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool has_forbidden_digit (unsigned int n)
{
  const bool FORBIDDEN [10] =
  {
    [3] = true,
    [6] = true,
    [9] = true,
  };

  do
  {
    if( FORBIDDEN[(n % 10)] )
    {
      return true;
    }
    n/=10;
  } while(n != 0);

  return false;
}
```

For example:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
  if(!has_forbidden_digit(i))
  {
    printf("%d\n", i);
  }
}
```

Comment: UV with minor aside: If `FORBIDDEN [0] == true`, then `is_forbidden_digit(0)` returns false. I'd expect true.  Perhaps a `do { ... } while(n != 0)` loop?

Comment: @chux Indeed, I didn't consider n=0 which is a special case. I'll change it to do-while. But apart from that it should filter out zeroes elsewhere in the number.

Comment: UV but I don't like the name `is_forbidden_digit`. `has_forbidden_digit` or `contains_forbidden_digit` would be more descriptive.

Comment: @IanAbbott Good point, fixed. I wrote `is_` out of habit since it was a function returning bool :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a separate function that checks whether a number contains a digit that is present in a set of target digits.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

_Bool is_present( const unsigned int a[], size_t n, int value )
{
    const int Base = 10;

    _Bool present = 0;

    do
    {
        unsigned int digit = abs( value % Base );

        size_t i = 0;
        while ( i < n && digit != a[i] ) i++;

        present = i != n;
    } while ( !present && ( value /= Base ) );

    return present;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const size_t N = 20;
    const unsigned int a[] = { 3, 6, 9 };

    printf( "Enter a number: " );

    int value;

    scanf( "%d", &value );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++value )
    {
        if ( !is_present( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ), value ) )
        {
            printf( "%d ", value );
            ++i;
        }
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a number: 100
100 101 102 104 105 107 108 110 111 112 114 115 117 118 120 121 122 124 125 127
```

In this case you can in main specify any set of forbidden digits. The function does not depend on the set because the set is passed as an argument to the function.